Нужнa ли запятая?
Она спрашивает(,) и снова для того, чтобы убедится в собственных догадках.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая на месте пропуска? Смысл предложения: она спрашивает и делает это (спрашивает) снова для того, чтобы убедиться в собственных догадках. В предложении опущено слово "спрашивает". Как правильно определить грамматическую основу?

Правильно:
Она спрашивает, и снова для того, чтобы убедиться в собственных догадках.
Пояснение

Простое двусоставное предложение она спрашивает, осложненное присоединительной конструкцией. В состав присоед.конструкции входит придаточное предложение цели, союз для того чтобы. Это односоставное инфинитивное предложение, главный член — независимый инфинитив.

О присоединительных конструкциях


Учебник, стр. 132:
   Присоединение — это включение члена предложения в 
   законченное по содержанию и форме высказывание в качестве 
   дополнительного замечания, пояснения: Он практически не 
   выходит на улицу, тем более в дождь; Он отправился в горы 
   ночью, и притом без проводника. 

Розенталь, § 24. Присоединительные конструкции. § 24.1
 Присоединительные члены предложения, которые содержат 
 дополнительные разъяснения или замечания, вводимые в 
 середину или в конец предложения, отделяются или выделяются 
 запятыми (реже — тире). Такие конструкции обычно 
 присоединяются словами даже, особенно, в особенности, 
 например, главным образом, в частности, в том числе, 
 притом, и притом, причём, и («и притом»), да, да и, да и 
 вообще, да и только и др.:  Вдруг рванул ветер, и  с такой 
 силой, что едва не выхватил у Егорушки узелок и рогожку 
 (Ч.);


В данном случае и снова для того — это присоединительный член предложения для основного предложения, союз И.  Местоименная часть для того составного союза для того, чтобы  относится к присоединительному члену, а затем следует придаточное инфинитивное предложение.

